# osTicket - Tooltips without information (Nginx)

Tags: nginx, osticket

I'm having an issue in osTicket.

Every tooltip in it contains no information, I  have a feeling it's something to do with Nginx, but I have no idea what.

Here's an image to illustrate my error:
https://i.gyazo.com/3d3c29c08bac5cb59aad2a57c5aa2035.png

Any help would be appreciated, Google brought me no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I don't claim to be an nginx expert so I can't offer a detailed explanation as to why it works, but I solved the same problem by adapting the configuration at https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/osticket/?highlight=osticket. The key fix seems to be adding:

```
set $path_info "";
if ($request_uri ~ "^/scp/.*\.php(/[^\?]+)") {
    set $path_info $1;
}
```

to your server block and

```
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;
```

to the location within it which serves the php files. Someone who is better at nginx than I am may be able to offer a better way of doing things and/or explain why this works.